# Message Signing using X509 certificate

Tags: c#, x509, pkcs#7

I am signing message using digital certificate in a asp.net web service using below code.
Signing is working fine expect signedMessage.ComputeSignature line is taking up to 30 to 40 seconds because of this i am face timeout exception. The same code when i am running under windows forms application is producing result in fraction of second. Any clue or help.

```
   public static string Encrypt(string fullMessage, string certificateName, bool deAttch)
    {
        X509Certificate2 signer = GetCertificate(certificateName);  
        byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fullMessage);  
        Oid contentOid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1", "PKCS 7 Data");
        SignedCms signedMessage = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(contentOid, contentBytes), deAttch);

        signedMessage.ComputeSignature(new CmsSigner(signer));

        byte[] signedBytes = signedMessage.Encode();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes).Trim();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether this should be a answer (I don't know what impact it cause, but i will find out). Just setting a property

```
cert.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
```

of

```
CmsSigner cert = new CmsSigner(signer);
```

where previously i was creating object using constructor and passing directly to method. Now it is working fine and not taking that much time.

```
   public static string Encrypt(string fullMessage, string certificateName, bool deAttch)
    {
        X509Certificate2 signer = GetCertificate(certificateName);  
        byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fullMessage);  
        Oid contentOid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1", "PKCS 7 Data");
        SignedCms signedMessage = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(contentOid, contentBytes), deAttch);
        CmsSigner cert = new CmsSigner(signer);
        cert.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;            
        signedMessage.ComputeSignature(cert);
        byte[] signedBytes = signedMessage.Encode();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes).Trim();
        }


        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string certificateName)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Where(cert => cert.Subject.IndexOf(certificateName) >= 0).FirstOrDefault();
        if (certificate == null)
            throw new Exception("Certificate " + certificateName + " not found.");

        return certificate;
    }
```

Comment: I checked it thoroughly X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly it decrease length of signature meaning only personal certificate is included in signature.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok will consider this next time

Comment: It worked for me too, you could tag this an answer! :)